# How to covert PL/SQL .sql file to SQL*PLUS so it can be run with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: batch-file, plsql, sqlplus

I'm trying to add the CONDITION_TEST.sql file to Windows Task Scheduler, so it will run automatically everyday.

I created a .bat file that has the following text:
**sqlplus userid/password@csdpro @C:\Users\userid\Desktop\HCR_Datamart_Recon\CONDITION_TEST.sql
echo commit; | userid/password$@csdpro**

The CONDITION_TEST.sql file is created using PL/SQL. The line that now starts with the @, used to be a "select from" statement. I saved that block as a separate .sql file.

```
DECLARE
v_chkt_dm date;v_chks_dm number;v_chkt_un date; v_dm_fix varchar2(20000);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
BEGIN
  Select /*+parallel (a,4)*/ trunc(max(a.action_timestamp))
   into v_chkt_dm
   from hcr_dm.hcr_dm_fact a;
  Select /*+parallel (a,4)*/ count(distinct a.src_table) 
   into v_chks_dm
   from hcr_dm.hcr_dm_fact a;
  Select /*+parallel (b,4)*/ trunc(max(b.action_timestamp))
   into v_chkt_un
   from hcr_sandbox.hcrdm_the_big_union b;
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 If v_chkt_un < trunc(sysdate) then
  If v_chkt_dm = trunc(sysdate) and v_chks_dm = 9 then
     execute immediate 'truncate table HCR_SANDBOX.HCR_DM_FIX';
     commit;
  Else
     execute immediate 'truncate table HCR_SANDBOX.HCR_DM_FIXED_SUM';
     commit;
  END IF;
 Else  
  @V:\AccountingOperations\Statutory\ReneeGuo\AUTO_BIG_UNION\DM_FIX.sql;
 commit;
 END IF;  
END;
```

After I run the scheduler, I got a screen like this (I typed the screen results below). The task stopped running after seeing the number 167, which I don't know what it means. Then if I hit ENTER, it will create a new integer on the next row.

I haven't been dealing with SQL*plus a lot, so not sure what's gone wrong. Can any one help me with this? Thanks!

```
c:\Windows\system32>sqlplus userid..... CONDITION_TEST.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Oct 24 09:10:35 2014

Copyright <c> 1982, 2010, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Prodution With the Partitioning,     
OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

167
168
169 _
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 lines to the bottom of the .sql script:

```
/
quit;
```

The forward slash command executes what is in the buffer.  From: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16605/toc.htm#i765097

```
/ (slash)

Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block which is 
stored in the SQL buffer. Does not list the command. Use slash (/) at the 
command prompt or line number prompt in SQL*Plus command line. The buffer 
has no command history and does not record SQL*Plus commands.
```

The quit command is needed otherwise when the script is done it will leave you in sqlplus. Also, if you call sqlplus with the -S for silent option, you won't get as much superfluous output.

Oh and you better change your password.  heh

Comment: Thanks for your help! It seems working after adding the / But currently the screen only says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." How can I make it say the status for each step? Like in PL/SQL, I can use dbms_output.put_line at different places to say "first condition met", "first condition failed", etc.

Comment: Read up on SQL*Plus's 'SET' commands.  You need "set serveroutput on" at a minimum.